# How to combine JS function date format?

Tags: javascript

I have a question about how to combine JS function date format with 2 format below :

```
<code class="jsdemo">$('#validMinMaxDatepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});</code>

<code class='jsdemo'>$('#validMinMaxDatepicker').datepicker({minDate: -14, maxDate: -1});</code>
```

Appreciate with your helps.
Thanks.

Comment: your question is too imprecise...

Comment: Is this what you are asking for? `$('#validMinMaxDatepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', minDate: -14, maxDate: -1});`

Comment: Thanks DCoder, very helpfully now OK.